# sum pivot value in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sum, pivot

```
 Select * From
         (SELECT convert(varchar,SUM(distance)) 
              As total_distance, DAY(start_time) Days 
            FROM t1
           Where id=6314 
             And start_time 
         Between '2018-02-01 18:30:00' 
             And '2018-02-09 18:00:00'
    GROUP BY DAY(start_time)
         ) d
         pivot
          (Max(total_distance)
           For Days in ([3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9])
          ) piv;


results-
3   4   5         6      7        8      9
0   0   50.2    44.32   42.34   43.38   41.32
```

i want a sum column for these values along with this result like ;-

```
sum    3    4   5        6        7         8    9
221.56 0    0   50.2    44.32   42.34   43.38   41.32
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683542/i-would-like-to-combine-rollup-with-pivot-is-that-an-option

Answer (score 0):

add the following to your result set of the query: the `CROSS APPLY` part.

```
    ;WITH t ([3] ,[4]  ,[5] ,[6] , [7], [8] ,[9])  as
    (
    SELECT 0 ,  0 ,  50.2 ,   44.32 ,  42.34 ,  43.38 ,  41.32
    )
    SELECT * 
     FROM t
        CROSS APPLY 
        (SELECT SUM(x.Val) 
        FROM 
            (
            VALUES ([3]),([4]),([5]),([6]),([7]),([8]),([9])
            ) X (VAL)
            ) P(SVal)
```

and here is the query with your input:

```
    ;WITH Pvt as 
    (
    select * from
    (SELECT convert(varchar,SUM(distance)) as total_distance, DAY(start_time) Days 
        FROM t1
        where id=6314 and start_time between '2018-02-01 18:30:00' and '2018-02-09 18:00:00'
        GROUP BY DAY(start_time)
    ) d
        pivot
        (max(total_distance)
        for Days in ([3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9])
        ) piv
    )
            SELECT * 
             FROM Pvt
                CROSS APPLY 
                (SELECT SUM(x.Val) 
                FROM 
                    (
                    VALUES ([3]),([4]),([5]),([6]),([7]),([8]),([9])
                    ) X (VAL)
                    ) P(SVal)
```

Comment: hi,thanks fr ur reply . but i m getting this error, please check, Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 17
Operand data type varchar is invalid for sum operator.

Comment: change the Convert(varchar, SUM(distance)) as total_distance to be decimal/numeric

Comment: but i want the value as float but its get converted like 22.45 becomes 22

Comment: Multiply the SUM by 1.0

Comment: look, i don't want to round off each value and then to have a float result. i want sum of each float value.

Comment: your distance column, what data type is it? if it is float, then you don't need to use the conversion to varchar, just use  sum(distance). and the sum of all columns will not be converted from 22.45 to 22. unless your distance column is a whole number (int, bigint etc) then you'll need to Sum(distance) * 1.0